# Getting imagecolorat() data from every pixel from image using php-gd loop

Tags: php, loops, gd, syntax-error

I'm trying to get rgb color info from every pixel using imagecolorat() and I'm not sure if my syntax to save rgb values into $xy() is correct. I'm looking at documentation but I'm still not understanding what is going wrong.

My error shows: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /sites/uploadresults.php on line 69

```
#loop to populate rgb values and save to array: $xy

    $imagew = imagesx($img);
    $imageh = imagesy($img);
    $xy = array(i);

    echo "Image (w,h): ($imagew, $imageh)<br/>";

    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $imagew; $x++) {
    for ($y = 0;$y <= $imageh; $y++ ) {
            $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
            $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

            #loop to save ($r,$g,$b) into $xy
            for ($i = 0; $i <= $xytotal; $i++) {
            $xy[i] = ($r, $g, $b);
            }



            echo "xy: $xy x: $x, y: $y <br/>";
            var_dump($r, $g, $b);
        }
    }
```

Entire code is here:
http://pastebin.com/ZNDEzXFK

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Richard... I'm this year's tech intern at FunnyGarbage, working to improve your Rich Mosaic project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it should be

```
$xy[i] = array($r, $g, $b);
```

IOW `$xy` is array of arrays, each subarray RGB triple?

BTW the line `$xy = array(i);` in the beginning looks suspicious, I think it should be just `$xy = array();`, ie you initialize it to empty array.